# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am writing Some Application for calculation for my school project the code I'm using is

```
Private Sub C1A_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles C1A.Leave
        If C1A.Text = "" Then
        Else
            C2A.Text = Double.Parse(C1A.Text) * Double.Parse(C1ER.Text)
            If SellMove.Checked = True Then
                C1NC.Text = Double.Parse(C1OC.Text) - Double.Parse(C1A.Text)
                C2NC.Text = Double.Parse(C2OC.Text) + Double.Parse(C2A.Text)
            ElseIf BuyMove.Checked = True Then
                C1NC.Text = Double.Parse(C1OC.Text) + Double.Parse(C1A.Text)
                C2NC.Text = Double.Parse(C2OC.Text) - Double.Parse(C2A.Text)
            End If
            C2A.Text = CDec(C2A.Text).ToString("N")
            C1A.Text = CDec(C1A.Text).ToString("N")
            C1NC.Text = CDec(C1NC.Text).ToString("N")
            C2NC.Text = CDec(C2NC.Text).ToString("N")
        End If
    End Sub
```

But I get the error of An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll VB.net

The problem is When C1OC And C2OC text is = 0 it works but if it is not 0 it show me the error.

Any Help Please

Comment: Please ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. That would include EXACTLY what line the exception is thrown on, the actual error message (not just the type of the exception) and the data that was in use at the time.  Presumably the issue is that you are passing a `String` that doesn't represent a number to one or more of those `Double.Parse` calls. The obvious solution is to not do that, i.e. don't call `Double.Parse` unless you know for a fact that the text does represent a number. That means validating first or validating and converting together using `Double.TryParse`.

Comment: By the way, assigning a `Double` to the `Text` of a control and then getting the resulting `String` back out and converting that to a `Decimal` and then formatting that as a `String` and assign it back to the `Text` of the same control is just all sorts of bad. You should start by turning `Option Strict On` and then fixing all your typing issues. Then, if you want a formatted `Decimal` in that control, convert the original `Strings` to `Decimals` in the first place, then format the result of the multiplication and put the result into the control in one step.